# Highstock Y-Axis labels overlap eachother

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickeblewis/3jgQc/2/) for the chart I am building.

My issues are:

- Y-Axis labels and percentages overlap. Is it possible to align them so that I have green percentages, the label "Two", then red percentages and finally the label "Three"? If you take a look at another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickeblewis/UxJU6/2/) it certainly looks tidier.
- Highstock shows its labels inside the graph grid. Can these be pushed to the outside so that the labelling looks more like the way my second JSFiddle displays them?

The first issue is most important for me to solve, and the second I could live with if I have to:

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        yAxis: [{
             title: {
                text: 'One',
                style: {
                    color: 'blue'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            }
        },
        {

             title: {
                text: 'Two',
                style: {
                    color: 'green'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value + '%';
                },
                style: {
                    color: 'green'
                }
            },
  opposite: true
        },
{

             title: {
                text: 'THree',
                style: {
                    color: 'red'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value + '%';
                },
                style: {
                    color: 'red'
                }
            },
  opposite: true
        }  
      ],

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });
}

});​
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can control those positions with a combination of [yAxis.labels.x](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.labels.x) and [yAxis.title.margin](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.title.margin).

For example the first yAxis:

```
        {
             title: {
                text: 'One',
                style: {
                    color: 'blue'
                },
                margin: 25 //push out 25 pixels
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                },
                x: -20 //push out 20 pixels
            }
        }
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/3jgQc/6/).

[image]